# How to force download after file_put_contents in CakePHP?

Tags: php

How can I download the content from the DB as `.txt` file and wrap it inside a folder name according to `lang`?

By the way I want to use zipArchive PHP.

This is my data after fetching

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [file_name] => "alpha"
            [content] => "alpha one"
            [lang] => "ko"
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [file_name] => "bravo"
            [content] => "bravo two"
            [lang] => "ko"
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [file_name] => "charlie"
            [content] => "charlie three"
            [lang] => "tw"
        )
    )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [file_name] => "alpha"
            [content] => "alpha two"
            [lang] => "tw"
        )
)
```

This should be the expected output inside zip file.

```
- filename.zip
    - tw <- folder
        - alpha.txt
            * alpha one // content
            * alpha two // content
        - charlie.txt
            * charlie three // content
    - ko
        - bravo.txt
            * bravo two // content
```

And I used `file_put_contents`.

```
foreach ($data as $result) {
    $content .= 'content "' . trim($result['content']) . '"' . "\n";

    file_put_contents($result['file_name'], $content);
}
```

Comment: Please properly describe the actual programming problems that you are facing with solving your task, and how they are related to CakePHP! Also please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!